# button in the same height with text

Tags: html

I want to add 2 buttons at the same height of the text or in the middle, but what I get is:
[image]

How can I do it?
the code:

```
<h3 style="float:left;">Change Ambient Light:&nbsp;</h3>
<button style="float:left;" type="button" onclick="changeAmbientLight('up')">+</button>
<button style="float:left;" type="button" onclick="changeAmbientLight('down')">-</button>
<br style="clear:both" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the floats to `display: inline-block` and add `vertical-align: middle`

```
h3, button {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Remove `float: left`